# Toggle class in Vue JS

Tags: vue.js

I'm looking to toggle a class using Vue JS. I've read through [The Class and Style bindings](http://vuejs.org/guide/class-and-style.html) documentation but I'm still struggling to figure out the correct way to toggle a class.

I've simplified my code for brevity, but essentially I have a list of 4 'plans', each one with a button which allows the user to select the plan they want to purchase. With the current code the active class is added but when you click a button from another plan the class remains on the now non-active plan.

Here is the HTML.

```
<div id="app">
<ul class="plans">
        <plan-component :
                        name="Basic"
        ></plan-component>

        <plan-component :
                        name="Recreational"
        ></plan-component>

        <plan-component :
                        name="Team"
        ></plan-component>

        <plan-component :
                        name="Club"
        ></plan-component>
      </ul>

      <template id="plan-component">
        <li v-bind:class="{ 'active-plan': isActive }">
          <h2 class="plan-name">{{ name }}</h2>
          <a href="#" v-on:click="makeActivePlan($event)" class="select-plan button">Choose this plan</a>
        </li>
      </template>
</div>
```

Here is the JS.

```
Vue.component('plan-component', {
        template: '#plan-component',

      props: ['name', 'isActive'],

      methods: {
        makeActivePlan(e) {
            // We dispatch an event setting this to become the active plan
                e.preventDefault();
                this.isActive = true;
            this.$dispatch('set-active-plan', this);
        }
      }

    });

    new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data: {
        activePlan: { name: 'n/a' }
      },

      events: {
        'set-active-plan': function(plan) {
            this.activePlan = plan;
        }
      },
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `plan-component` is closely related with its parent, you could use the `$parent` property to get/set the active plan:

```js
Vue.component('plan-component', {
  template: '#plan-component',

  props: ['name'],

  computed: {
    isActive () {
     return this.$parent.activePlan.name === this.name
    }
  },
  
  methods: {
    makeActivePlan () {
      this.$parent.activePlan.name = this.name
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  
  data: {
    activePlan: { name: 'Club' }
  }
})
```

```css
.active-plan { color: red }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.25/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <ul class="plans">
    <plan-component name="Basic"></plan-component>
    <plan-component name="Recreational"></plan-component>
    <plan-component name="Team"></plan-component>
    <plan-component name="Club"></plan-component>
  </ul>

  <template id="plan-component">
    <li :class="{ 'active-plan': isActive }" @click.prevent="makeActivePlan">
      <h2 class="plan-name">{{ name }}</h2>
    </li>
  </template>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use events to retain flexibility and re-usability, another approach could be as under:

```js
Vue.component('plan-component', {
    template:'#plan-component',
    props:['name', 'isActive'],
    methods:{
 makeActivePlan(){
     this.$dispatch('set-active-plan', this.name);
 }
    }
});

new Vue({
 el:'#app',
 events:{
           'set-active-plan'(name){
  this.setActivePlan(name)
     }
 }
 data(){
     return{
  planOptions:[
      {name:'Basic', isActive:true},
      {name:'Recreational', isActive:false},
      {name:'Team', isActive:false},
      {name:'Club', isActive:false}
  ]
     }
 },
 methods:{
     setActivePlan(name){
         this.planOptions.forEach(plan => {
      plan.isActive = false;
      if(plan.name === name){
          plan.isActive = true
      }
          });
      }
 }
});
```

Then the html would be :

```html
<div id='app'>
    <ul class="plans">
 <plan-component 
     v-for="plan in planOptions"
     :name="plan.name"
     :isActive="plan.isActive"
 ></plan-component>
    </ul>
 
 <template id="plan-component">
        <li :class="{ isActive: 'active-plan' }" @click.prevent="makeActivePlan">
          <h2 class="plan-name">{{ name }}</h2>
        </li>
      </template>
</div>
```

I have not tested the code but it should work as intended. If you face any difficulties post a comment here and I will try to help.